# USB-C to USB-A to Micro for charging

Tags: cables, usb-c

The project is to add 2 USB-A ports to my bass amp so I can charge my device(s) during a gig.  To do that, I bought a 2-port USB panel mount connector (intended to connect to a motherboard) and a 2-port plugin charger.  The idea was to cut off the header connector and replace it with 2 USB Males to plug into the charger.  The problem is the charger has 1 USB-A and 1 USB-C port.  Can I just put on a C male end on the bare wires, or put an A male end on the bare wires and use a A-to-C adapter to plug into the charger?

Edit: The "Micro" in the title refers to the cable that goes from the panel mount Type A connector to the actual device being charged.

Edit 2: In talking about this with friends, this question was unclear to them.  The plan is to tap into the AC mains inside the amplifier cabinet and run it to an outlet, also mounted inside the cabinet.  Then I plug the 2-port wall-wart charger into that outlet.  The from the 2 USB ports of the charger, run cables to the USB-A panel-mount.  The question is if I put a USB-C male on the end of one of those cables and plug it into the charger, will I be able to plug my phone into the other end of that same cable and have it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think easiest way would be to get different charger with 2 or more USB A ports.

The adapter might work, but I highly doubt it. Look for something like [this one](https://ca.shein.com/USB-3-1-Type-C-4-Port-USB-Adapter-Hub-p-2158273-cat-2486.html).

Finally, you can use [BOB-15100](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15100) breakout board or make something like that yourself to draw power from USB-C. You can find an explanation [here](https://forum.digikey.com/t/simple-way-to-use-usb-type-c-to-get-5v-at-up-to-3a-15w/7016). Solder the wires coming from panel directly to the board and then connect it to charger with standard USB-C cable.